# Morse Code Vibration Xcode 9 Swift 4

Tags: ios, vibration

I am building an iOS app that will vibrate your message in morse code. 
I am having a really hard time setting an exact vibration time. 
International Morse code requires 250ms vibrations, and also different paused lengths, and I cant seem to find a way to set an exact length for the vibration.

I have already tried

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(/All Vibration Codes/)
```

I am willing to use either Objective-C or Swift, but the app is natively programmed in swift. Preferably code for Swift 4 and Xcode 9. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: OK, never mind. The question I marked as duplicate uses private APIs.

Comment: There is no solution without private api, Apple not giving control on vibration... I’m sorry but it’s impossible to implement now